# Pegar dados no DB Mysql usando AJAX/PHP para criar um badge contendo a contagem de itens do DB

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Preciso pegar uma contagem de itens no meu DB Mysql usando ajax e php.

Meu ajax esta assim:

```
<code> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#badgewel').empty(); //Limpa a tabela
    $.ajax({
    type:'get',     //método HTTP usado
    dataType: 'json',   //tipo de retorno
    url: '../badge.php',//arquivo php onde serão buscados os dados
    success: function(dados){
        $('#badgewel').text(dados);
        }
    }
    });
    });

</code>
```

E meu arquivo PHP esta assim:

```
<code>

    <?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect('XXXX','XXXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXXX');
    if (!$con){
    die('Não pode conectar:' .mysql_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"badge");
    $sql="SELECT
    idProd,
    COUNT(idProd) AS Total
    FROM Produtos";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row ['Total'];//testei a pagina badge.php e funcionou
    echo json_encode($row);
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
</code>
```

No HTML tenho um trecho onde os dados serão exibidos (um badge bootstrap):

```
<code>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>teste badge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
    <script src="../js/badgewel.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"     async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <h3>Isso é um teste de badge</h3>
        <span><label>Total &nbsp;</label><p id="badgewel" class="badge"></p>
    </span>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>

</code>
```

Ocorre que não esta exibindo nada, ele tinha de exibir o total mas nada acontece!

Comment: Será que dá certo trocar "$('#badgewel').text(dados);" por "$('#badgewel').html(dados);" ? Minha sugestão...

Comment: O código SQL poderia omitir o primeiro campo também, ficando assim: "SELECT COUNT(idProd) AS Total FROM Produtos" - iria retornar apenas um campo com a contagem de registros.

Comment: Opa, vou testar suas dicas!

Comment: Não funcionou, não aparece nada!

Comment: Porque tem o js/php envolvido em `<code>`?

Comment: Não entendi @Miguel!

Comment: tem `<code>` no seu código ou colocou aqui só para exemplo?

Comment: @Miguel, só exemplo

Comment: Opa pessoal, ainda não consegui fazer funcionar esse meu codigo!!

Answer (score 1):

No seu código jQuery tem um fechamento de chave a mais que uma abertura.

Com a correção fica assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#badgewel').empty(); //Limpa a tabela

    $.ajax({
        type:'get',     //método HTTP usado
        dataType: 'json',   //tipo de retorno
        url: '../badge.php',//arquivo php onde serão buscados os dados
        success: function(dados){
            $('#badgewel').text(dados);
        }
    });
});
```

Note que identei seu código e desta forma ficou mais fácil de achar a sobra no fechamento das chaves.

Além disso recomendo que remova o "echo $row ['Total'];" do seu código PHP pois ele não está codificado como JSON nessa linha e isso poderia gerar uma inconsistencia na hora de converter o valor de JSON para texto na sua requisição AJAX.

**Editado:**

Sobre o erro persistir após alteração da ordem dos arquivos (colocando primeiro o jQuery e depois o badgewel.js:

Remova o modificador "async defer" do script badgewel.js, pois desta forma ele é carregado assíncronamente. O browser pode interpretar isto de diversas formas, dependendo da implementação, mas no geral ele carrega assincronamente, ou seja pode ainda que em desordem no head da sua página carregar antes do script do jQuery.

Ao remover estas tags e deixar o carregamento do badgewel.js por último você informa que o carregamento da página deve ser síncrono e portanto na ordem que você definiu a linkagem da página com seus scripts.

**Editado 2:**

Notei que você está incluíndo o jQuery através de uma URL segura (https). O correto é incluir o arquivo de acordo com o protocolo de sua página, do contrário não há como garantir que ele será carregado.

A menos que sua página utilize https altere o endereço para uma versão com http neste ou em outro servidor que disponibilize o jQuery.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Opa amigo! Não sei o que ta rolando de errado, mas ainda não funcionou. Desculpe, mas sou meio iniciante ainda e talvez esteja comentendo algum deslize bobo.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta e coloquei meu html todo pra vc dar uma olhada pra ver se tem algum erro ok. Agradeço sua ajuda!

Comment: Vi aqui agora no firebug que esta ocorrendo um erro: ReferenceError: $ is not defined em $(document).ready(function()){. Obs: Estou carregando o jquery de um CDN.

Comment: Editei minha resposta com a possível solução, tendo em vista seu comentário e a resposta do Albo Vieira.

Comment: Opa, eu ja havia mudado isso tmb e nada!! Esta tudo correto no html na tag p?

Comment: Encontrei mais um problema. Nova edição adicionada a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Vi aqui agora no firebug que esta ocorrendo um **erro:**

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined em $(document).ready(function()){. Obs: Estou carregando o jquery de um CDN.

Isso ocorre porque você esta carregando seu javascript antes do jquery.

Comment: Opa, ja troquei a ordem e persiste o erro no firebug!!!

Answer (score 0):

Patrão fiz assim deu certo aqui... Aí se adapta no seu código.

Posso estar errado, mas no seu código "dados" só tá declarado para a saída e não para receber do php(não sei se é isso, é o que eu "acho").

Aí se precisa mudar o "sql do php", pq fiz com minhas tabelas.

html.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>teste badge</title>
<link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jqueryfull.js"></script><!--meu jquery-->
<script src="js.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script><!--o js-->

</head>
<body>
<div>
<h3>Isso é um teste de badge</h3>
    <span><label>Total &nbsp;</label><p id="badgewel" class="badge"></p>
</span>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

js.js

```
$.post('php.php', $("#badgewel").serialize(), function(data) {
$('#badgewel').html(data);
$('#badgewel').text(data);
});
```

php.php

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
if (!$con){
die('Não pode conectar:' .mysql_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"test");
$sql="SELECT nome_carac FROM carac";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ 
   echo $row["nome_carac"];
   echo json_encode($row);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Vê se ajuda qq coisa comenta que agente ajusta...

Comment: Boa noite amigo, fiz as suas modificações mas mesmo assim ainda não aparace nada. Estranho pq quando rodo só o php com echo ele apresenta o valor da contagem do item que eu quero no banco, mas quando uso o html+ajax, não rola!!!

Comment: Bom realmente não faço ideia... Se o jquery tá declarado, e tá tudo cetim sei naum...